# Conditional rendering in react-list items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying make conditional rendering in react list item but it's not working:

here is what i tried:

this is my state:

```
menuItems: [
        {
          title: "Home",
          partly: false,
          icon: home,
          route: '/'
        }
....
      ]
```

here is my list in jsx:

```
render() {
    return (
{this.state.menuItems.map(item => (
             <NavLink
             className={
               item.partly
                 ? "content--item item-partly"
                 : "content--item"
             }
             onMouseEnter={() => this.showPartly(item)}
             onMouseLeave={() => this.hidePartly(item)}
             to={item.route}
           >
             <p>{item.title}</p>
           </NavLink>
          ))}
      )
}
```

and here is my onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events:

```
showPartly = item => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      let item = Object.assign({}, prevState.item);  
      item.partly = true;                        
      console.log(item.partly)           
      return { item }; 
    })
}

 hidePartly = item => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      let item = Object.assign({}, prevState.item);  
      item.partly = false;                        
      console.log(item.partly)           
      return { item }; 
    })
}
```

i can see on console true and false when events work. But it's not affect to dom so my classname not changes.

Where i mistake?

Comment: First of all add a key prop to your `NavLink` inside the map

Comment: added, nothing changes

Comment: Do you have `item` & `menuItems` a separate state? Post you somplete state.

Comment: there is my complete state. i don't have item like a seperate state

Comment: I think the problem is that your return an object inside of an object.
Try this: `return {...item }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting up the only item, so your state looks like:

```
{
 menuItems: [{}, {}, {}],
 item: {}
}
```

I'd rather set up the new `menuItems` array to the state, or even check `partly` in another field.

The way, which modifies `menuItems`:

```
showPartly = item => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
       return {
         menuItems: prevState.menuItems.map(
           current => current === item ? {...current, partly: true} : current
         ),
       };
    })
}

 hidePartly = item => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
       return {
         menuItems: prevState.menuItems.map(
           current => current === item ? {...current, partly: false} : current
         ),
       };
    })
}
```

And the way with the separated field in the state:

```
render() {
    return (
{this.state.menuItems.map(item => (
             <NavLink
             className={
               this.state.partly === item
                 ? "content--item item-partly"
                 : "content--item"
             }
             onMouseEnter={() => this.showPartly(item)}
             onMouseLeave={() => this.hidePartly(item)}
             to={item.route}
           >
             <p>{item.title}</p>
           </NavLink>
          ))}
      )
}
// ...

showPartly = item => {
  this.setState({partly: item});
}

 hidePartly = item => {
   this.setState({partly: null});
 }
```

Important thing: in the second variant you can have only one partly item

Comment: Thank you so much it's worked and i understand problem